# MySQL master slave replication

Tags: mysql

I had MySQL master/slave replication working properly but suddenly replication stopped and accidentally someone has changed mysql.binxxx file in salve so I am getting this error

> ERROR: 'Got fatal error 1236'.

So I checked latest mysql.bin and log poss from master and changed in slave so replication started but now again new mysql.binxxx created in server so again I am getting fatal error. Is there any fix solution for this without any data loss.

Answer (score 0):

If your instance is not that big, your best bet would be to recreate your slave from scratch.

You won't be losing data since from what I understand, your master is fine.